# How bad does the major GPA need to be for providing explanation in grad school app

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics, grades

I’m a sophomore in US college majoring in mathematics. I plan to apply for math PhD. I’m wondering how bad does the major GPA need to be for giving explanation? For example, do we need to provide explanations for a single A- out of straight-A’s?

Also, factors to take into account also include core courses (real analysis, abstract algebra, topology, etc.) vs. electives (combinatorics, number theory, probability, etc.), other courses taking along together e.g. 2 major classes in a semester vs. 4 major classes in a semester.

Comment: If the school has a cut-off, i.e. 3.5 and you have a 3.2, it would be prudent. But if the difference is 3.99 and 4.00, I would recommend that you spend the space on other topics.

Comment: Your GPA really only matters if it’s below about 3.5. Above that, other factors start to matter more.

Comment: @JeffE thank you so much for your answer! will your answer still apply if I apply to top schools and compete with other students who have similar statistics as me? In other word, between two seemingly equally qualified students, what will become a tipping point in eyes of admission committee?

Comment: "In other word, between two seemingly equally qualified students, what will become a tipping point in eyes of admission committee?" See this question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/45476/what-are-mathematics-graduate-schools-looking-for